# Can a dying power supply make a file-write fail in this way?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, crash, file-corruption

Lately my research code has been crashing during (or possibly milliseconds after) GPU-intensive draw operations, causing instant system restarts. As a test, I had my code save a file right after each draw operation. I noticed that when a crash happened and the machine restarted, the last written file would occasionally turn out to be corrupted. It might be shorter than normal, as though the write had been interrupted. Or, more interestingly, it might end with a long string of null characters. I have an example file that got cut off in the middle of a long series of floating-point values. After hundreds of thousands of correctly printed floating point numbers, there's a long string of null characters going to the end of the file:

`...0.501071078140873482631434399082 0.846616753214301076546632884856 -0.21299023\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...`

In this example, there are about three million nulls before the file ends. I believe the file's total length is still shorter than what it should be.

At first I thought this was a problem with my code, some memory management issue that manifested on the GPU side by causing the whole system to crash, maybe due to unstable NVIDIA drivers. However, I soon realized that I had a hardware problem, since other uses of my graphics card, like the Fire Strike and Heaven benchmarks, were causing the same system restarts.

Replacing the power supply seems to have stopped the crashes. But I want to make sure that the corrupted save files I produced were caused by the power supply failing in the middle of writing them, and not by some coincidental hard-to-catch bug in my code. This requires assuming that a PSU failure caused by load on the GPU can take a few milliseconds to occur, long enough for my code's drawing operation to have completed and for file writing to have begun.

I have thought about verifying this by turning off the power switch on my new PSU while saving the same kinds of files and looking for the same strings of null characters in them after restarting. I prefer to ask around before doing something so dangerous.

I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit. The disk is solid-state hybrid drive: Seagate FireCuda SSHD 2TB (ST2000DX002-2DV164).

Comment: yes, an abrupt stop can cause file corruption for files that are open at that time. Software crashes can cause corruption in files that are open and being written to, though it is less likely, since the write would have to be in progress to corrupt the file. Be sure that your code uses a try...finally or equivalent around file writes, so you can be sure to close the file cleanly.